# How to set a value in a field in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

Please, i want to put a value of a function in a field. my function return different results thats why i made :

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        return {'value': {'field': value}}
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what is your goal. [Read more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a great question.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a value like a parameter: 'vals'

OpenERP v7,

`def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
     return {'value': {'your_field_name': vals }}`

Odoo(OpenERP v8)

`def create(self,vals):
     return {'value': {'your_field_name': vals }}`

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to override create method and then super method calling required.

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    ### here you can change the value of the fields 
    vals.update({'field': value})
    ## then call the super method
    return super(class_name, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 8/9 API

```
@api.model
def create(self,values):
      values.update({'field_name': value})
      ## then call the super method
      return super(ClassName, self).create(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    ### here you can change the value of the fields 
    vals.update({'field': value})
    ## then call the super method
    return super(class_name, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```